# Fastest way to get shell icon

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, shell, icons

I'm using this code for getting the shell icon (the one displayed in Windows Explorer).
Does anyone has an experience with a faster way to get these icons ? The `SHGetFileInfo` seems to be quite slow.

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FileInfo: TSHFileInfo;
begin
  FillChar(FileInfo, SizeOf(FileInfo), 0);
  if SHGetFileInfo(PChar('c:\windows\'), 0, FileInfo, SizeOf(FileInfo),
    SHGFI_ICON or SHGFI_SMALLICON or SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX) <> 0 then 
    DrawIconEx(Canvas.Handle, 10, 10, FileInfo.hIcon, 0, 16, 16, 0, DI_IMAGE or 
      DI_MASK);
end;
```

Thanks!

Comment: I've used this method in the past with no problems from a C++ application. There's a slight difference though, I only used the flags `SHGFI_ICON` and `SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES`.

Comment: Yes, definately use `SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES` if speed is an issue.  With that, `SHGetFileInfo()` skips querying the actual file for its attributes, which can take some time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the **SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES** flag as well. See the articles [`Tuning SHGetFileInfo for Optimum Performance`](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/shell/article.php/c4511) and [`What does SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES mean?`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/06/01/145428.aspx) for more information.

Comment: +1, a quick series of measurements (getting the file icon info 10k times) confirmed me the best is your suggestion (from approx. 18s to 11s). My suggestion (use the shell image list) tune that up to approx. 10s where about 0.5s takes the initial getting of the image list handle.

Answer (score 3):

I have used a cache when I used SHGetFileInfo. Unless it is an .exe or .ico file (and perhaps a few more) the icon will be the same for the same file extension, so when you show a dir list you can use the same icon for files of the same type and you don't have to call (and wait for) SHGetFileInfo again.

Comment: How do you know what to cache? Any type can have dynamic icons, %1 for .ico and .bmp etc and shell extensions for any type...

Comment: @TLama, the idea with the cache is to avoid calling SHGetFileInfo for each file because it is slow so it is only necessary to call it when encountering new file types.

Comment: @Anders, yes, you are right, it is not completely safe because different types may not have fixed icons.