# How can I know whether the next SHGetFileInfo (SHGFI_ICON) call will be slow (for exe files etc.)?

Tags: windows, winapi, icons

I am writting a file manager. When it opens, the UI freezes for a while. I profiled it and find the slow function is `SHGetFileInfo`.

```
SHFILEINFO shinfo;
SHGetFileInfo(FullPath.c_str(), NULL, &shinfo, sizeof(shinfo),
    SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_LARGEICON))
```

Also, the program runs fast enough even when there are hundreds of folders, but becomes extremely slow when there is at least one executable. I think loading icon from such files is a heavy task since the resources must be loaded.

I see that when Windows Explorer loads a folder, all icons except executables are correct, and executables have their default icons (the icon of command line utilities). Then their icons become correct in a few seconds.

My question is how can Explorer determine which icons are fast to load and which are slow? I think checking for the extension `.exe` is not reliable because one may do `assoc .foo=exefile` or set another extension's icon to `%1`, etc.

Comment: It's probably just spawning some background threads to load the icons - the fast ones finish first.

Comment: @RogerRowland thanks, I am looking at the Process Explorer. When I repeatly press F5 the executable icons quickly toggle between the generic icon and the correct icons, but the count of threads in Explorer.exe is a constant 64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows shell uses a couple of mechanisms to deal with this performance hit:

1. It looks up icons in a background thread. Explorer is still perfectly usable whilst this thread is doing its work.
2. Explorer caches icons. This means that the icon extraction is performed once only and the result is remembered.

I think if you want your file manager to be as usable as Explorer then you will need to implement similar optimisations. Or perhaps `SHGetFileInfo` already takes advantage of the system icon cache.

These articles relating to shell icon performance may be useful to you:

- [Fastest way to get shell icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229804/fastest-way-to-get-shell-icon)
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/06/01/145428.aspx
- https://www.catch22.net/tuts/win32/system-image-list

Comment: It seems that `SHGetFileInfo` can use the system cache. If my program opens a folder with executables twice, the second load will be much faster. I tried loading icons in (one) thread but the executable is blocking the following files from showing correct icons. I want the fast ones show first and then the executables, like Explorer.

Comment: So leave executable files until last. Skip the standard executable extensions, .exe and .com.

Comment: I thought it is not reliable before, as the question said. I copied HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.foo (both point to `exefile`), and copies the Sysinternals folder but renames the `.exe`s to `.foo`s. Interestingly explorer treats these files as if they were regular files and shows their real icons instantly. Maybe it just checks "executable extensions" as you said.

Comment: You don't need perfect recognition of file types here. Simple extension check will give you very close to perfect recognition anyway. And it is cheap.